# Insert Into on Duplicate Update creates me an unwanted row

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, sql-insert

I have a SQL query as follows-

```
"INSERT INTO users(id, rank) SELECT v.user, v.vote FROM votes v WHERE
 v.assertion = '$ID' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
rank = ( CASE WHEN v.vote = '1' THEN rank+50 WHEN v.vote = '-1' 
THEN rank-200 WHEN v.vote = '3' THEN rank+100 ELSE rank END)"
```

applied on a database with a table `users` with and id and rank field, and a `votes` table with a user and vote field. I have to update the rank of the users in the users table based on their vote.

I really like this kind of query, but I've noticed a problem: every time I execute this from my PHP script the query adds a row to the users table completely empty (with only an ID, which is A_I, and a rank of 1, when usually there would be other field as well). I can't really wrap my head around why this happens.

Any help/idea?

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to. Can you show some example tables / data to demonstrate this (possibly in sqlfiddle).

Comment: Show the full schema of table

Comment: is there unique key on id field of users table? and you are trying to inserting a duplicate row based on this same id (user) in 2nd time?

Comment: are you sure that v.user and v.vote is already exist ?

Comment: Trying to get sql fiddle to work, meanwhile I'll post the pastebin, hope it helps. http://pastebin.com/heiXJZsi Thanks!

Comment: Just as a comment, your logic appears strange. If someone had (say) 2 vote rows, one with 1 vote and one with 100 votes then your insert could give different values of rank depending on which row MySQL chose to process from the select first.

Comment: Hope this is how it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee40b

Comment: Looking at your tables, I tend to suspect the main issue here might be your php, possibly executing the INSERT an extra time with a random $ID value.

Comment: I tried your SQL fiddle, doing a select of users, and trying again having done an example of your INSERT. The ranks changed (as I would expect) but no extra rows were inserted either way

Comment: My PHP is http://pastebin.com/vP6aHFDs, I don't get where I could be doing the duplicate INSERT. Thank you so much for your help for now :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons :

1. The id column is not the primary key, and probably you table doesn't have a primary key at all.

Create a primary key like this :

```
alter table user add primary key (id)
```

2. If you insert an value of `0` in an auto increment column, a new id is generated. An auto incremented column must not contain the value `0`.

There is also a more general problem with your approach : in fact you only insert the user id and the rank, other compulsory fields in the table (username) are missing. The `insert` part does not seem to be valid for this reason. If you use an `insert on duplicate key update`, you must make sure that the result is correct which ever of insert and update is executed.

Comment: id is the primary of users, and id,assertion are the primaries of votes. Isn't that correct?

Comment: It was indeed a 0 value in the A_I ID field. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not have a primary key first provide a primary key to id

run this sql query 
alter table user add primary key (id) 
and than try it will work

Comment: Already tried to, even dropped and created it again. Same problem.

Comment: can you show the full database schema ?? so that i could address the error.